# Why dart type casting affects the original casted variable

Tags: dart

I am learning dart programming language version 2.14.3 and came across an odd issue that I am unable to understand.

The following code doesn't compile obviously because `isEven` is only defined in `int` class.

```
void main() {
  const num someNumber = 3;
  print(someNumber.isEven);
}
```

However, casting `someNumber` to `int` and assigning the value to a different variable, solved the problem and the code compiles with `print(someNumber.isEven);` not changed. The following code compiles.

```
void main() {
  const num someNumber = 3;
  final someInt = someNumber as int;
  print(someNumber.isEven);
}
```

Is this a bug in dart or a language feature that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```dart
final someInt = someNumber as int;
print(someNumber.isEven);
```

If the cast fails, an uncaught  `TypeError` will be thrown and exit your function.  Therefore, the compiler can logically deduce that, if `print(someNumber.isEven)` is reached, `someNumber` must be an `int`.  Therefore, on lines that follow the cast, the original object is *promoted* to the casted type. (Note that [only local variables or instance variables that are both `final` and private can be promoted](https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons#property-or-this).) Put another way, the cast acts as a type assertion; you don't need the `someInt` variable:

```dart
someNumber as int;
print(someNumber.isEven);
```

This is the same principle by which `!` (which is basically a non-null cast operator) can promote a local nullable variable to be non-nullable and avoid the need to pepper `!` for subsequent accesses to the same variable.

Comment: I was going to ask why `assert(someNumber is int);` doesn't work the same way but I found the issue you posted [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36883). Thank you that was clear.